# Django Find parent by two children

Tags: django, orm, django-orm

```
class Company(models.Model):  
    title = models.CharField()  

class Office(models.Model):  
    сompany = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    title = models.CharField()  

class Human(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    office = models.ManyToManyField(Office)
```

how to find current user's company without using Prefetch. Because it's expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
>> user = request.user
>> Company.objects.filter(office__human__user=user)
```

Here I am reverse querying User from Company via `Company --> Office --> Human --> User`. More information can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

Comment: Gives an error message "Cannot query "user@mail.ru": Must be "Office" instance". It turns out that he does not see beyond one external model?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Solved the problem like this: Office.objects.filter(humans__user=request.user).select_related('сompany')

Comment: I ran my code with the example model you have shared here. It worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Office.objects.filter(humans__user=request.user).select_related('сompany')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).